# Get the topics from a repository

Tags: github, github-api

In this api call `https://api.github.com/repos/octobat/Hello-world` what should it be added to have also the topics of repo?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-all-repository-topics

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk so it is not possible adding it to the url?

Comment: No, it doesn't say it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the custom media type `application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json` in the `Accept` header will add the `topics` array :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"
```

Sample output :

```
...
"topics": [
    "language-grammars",
    "language-statistics",
    "linguistic",
    "syntax-highlighting"
  ],
...
```

Note that for https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-world you will have an empty array since this repo doesn't have any topic